# Youtube API Python and mySQL. TypeError: string indices must be integers. How to fix?

Tags: python, mysql, youtube-api

so I am doing a project for Youtube API and need to search for movies. It is connected to my mySQL database which is called moviereviews. I have a table named films inside and have columns inside that table such as "title", or "description", etc, which you will see in my code. I need to run my Python code so that the records that I have get inserted into my mySQL database. I am getting a string indices error so I am in need of help on how to fix it. I currently can only run one movie but need to run 3 for my project. I also do not know if the rest of my code is correct after the current error I have. Took my api key out. Hope I can get some help, thank you.

```
import mysql.connector
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


api_key = ''
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

moviereview = youtube.search().list(q="Tenet - Movie Review", part="id,snippet", type='video', maxResults=0, pageToken=None)
response = moviereview.execute()


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                               user='kkkoenn',
                               password='onnnnnoo',
                               database = "moviereview"
                               )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

for movie in response:
    title = movie['title']       #"this is where I am getting the error"
    description = movie['description']
    frame = movie['thumbnails']
    releaseDate = movie['publishDate']
    channel = movie['channelTitle']

    sql = "INSERT INTO films (Title, Description, Frame, ReleaseDate, Channel) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = (title, description, frame, releaseDate, channel)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()


print("records inserted")
```

Comment: Check what `movie` contains. You might be getting an array of array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here response is a dictionary. So you first have to get the items using
`response ['items']`. And then you can first print each item and check the properties of the item itself.

It is best to use `.get` method to access any object with default in order to not get any inclusion errors. Example: `response.get('items', [])`

```
movies = response.get('items', [])
for movie in movies:
    print(movie)
    print(type(movie))
    title = movie['title']  # or equivalent movie.get('title', None) would work
    description = movie['description']
    frame = movie['thumbnails']
    releaseDate = movie['publishDate']
    channel = movie['channelTitle']
```

Comment: So if I did response.get('items', []) would I have to had every object such as title, description etc individually? Like response.get('items', [title]) ? And also,  I have to make the response.get  before the for loop correct? @VaibhavPatel

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: So when I used title = movie['title'] I got the error output KeyError: 'title'. However, when I tried movie.get('title', None), I got the error output TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable. Not sure what this means. @VaibhavPatel

Comment: Can you print what movie object contains and have you added the `movies = response.get('items', [])` line?

Comment: I did print(movie) and got the output of the movie "tenet" which I have set in my search list. And yes, movies = response.get('items', []) was included when I ran the code. @VaibhavPatel

Comment: Although now that I think about it, when I did print(movie), I removed everything below mycursor = mydb.cursor() from the code. I then just inserted print(movie) at the bottom so it might of just ran the youtube search list request. How or where do I print the movie object to see what it contains, or did I do it correctly? @VaibhavPatel

Comment: I updated the print positions can you share the answer for only the first two prints?

Comment: Ok I ran both print positions from the top of my code to the two print positions at the bottom and got the output for the movie tenet. @VaibhavPatel

Comment: what is the type?

Comment: <class 'dict'> @VaibhavPatel